# There is no libproject inside google play services( Rev. 30) in eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I don't know what happened but I could not find any libproject inside google play services. I have just update it. My apk file has become jar file after cleaning the project, so I checked the google play services and I found that there is no libproject to add into the project. there are docs and samples but on libproject.

I haven't found any solution on the web, so I think it is best to post here. 
Is there any problem with this update?

Anyone, please give me any idea to solve this problem.

Comment: I think this related [SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat) can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find them in /extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms, if you also updated Google Repository through the SDK Manager.

The individual libraries are in aar format, so you'll have to extract the jar yourself, if that's what you're after.

Comment: ther is no libproject folder in the path you provided

Comment: Note, the steps work, but you need to use play-services-6.5.87. Step 1: Browse to : \extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\6.5.8‌​7 Step 2: copy play-services-6.5.87.aar and change it to a .zip, then extract it somewhere (or use 7-zip to extract it to its own folder) Step 3: import this into your eclipse workbench. Right click on it and go to properties>android. Set it as a library Step 4: Go to your project's properties>android and add this library. Worked for me! Have fun.

Answer (score 5):

I am working on a legacy project in Eclipse and I fixed the problem a slightly different way than the others. For me using the project from Google Play Services revision 29, had all sorts of dependency problems which I could not resolve. For example it wanted the compatibility library v4 so I imported it but even then it could not find some required resources.

However, I was able to use **Revision 28** without such issues and set the minimum version of my app to be ICS. Below is a link to version 28. Download it, unzip it and extract the **libproject** folder to where it would normally have been prior to removal.

Import the project in Eclipse (ensure copy files is selected) the usual way and all will be fine.

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8298000_r28.zip

Additional info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat/37356709#37356709):

Answer (score 0):

At first the arr file has to be converted into jar file and then extract them. Then the classes.jar file should be transferred to the libs folder.