# Google Play Services revision 30 missing version.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I'm busy working on a legacy android application on eclipse and I need the latest version of google play services. In particular, I require the value of
`@Integer/google_play_services_version`. In previous versions this would be stored in

```
<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/version.xml
```

however google have chosen to break down this latest version into multiple libraries and I can no longer find `version.xml` anywhere. If necessary I am willing to hardcode the version number, while not the ideal solution, but I obviously can't find this either. Any tips?

EDIT: I should note that I've successfully installed the latest m2repositry and integrated within my application play-services-ads from the aar inside there.

Comment: why are u still using eclipse and not android studio?

Comment: @Manny264 I've tried migrating to Android Studio in the past but there are legacy OCR dependencies that don't play nice with gradle. Either way, as far as I know just getting the version number would be a far easier fix for me than going through the headache of trying to adapt it to android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `res/values/values.xml` (which contains the `google_play_services_version`) inside the `play-services-basement` aar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in using Eclipse. Are you aware that [Eclicpse is no longer officially supported](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html) for Android Development. Using Eclipse may be preventing you to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project.

To migrate to the Android Studio from Eclipse just follow this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) from Google developers.

For your problem about Google Play Service rev 30, I think this threads can help you with that.

- [Missing “/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject” folder after update to revision 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat)
- [There is no libproject inside google play services( Rev. 30) in eclipse Juno](http://cudou.com/pages/dhehgaah-there-is-no-libproject-inside-google-play-services-rev-30-in-eclipse-juno.html)