# Google play service library Revision 31, not found in Eclipse folder

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, google-play-services

I am using Eclipse ADT and I'm attempting to find the latest Google Play Services library **Google Play Services Library Revision
    31**, but this library does not appear on the Eclipse SDK folder; where can I find this library to download manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in using Eclipse. Are you aware that [Eclicpse is no longer officially supported for Android Development](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html). Using Eclipse may be preventing you to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project.

To migrate to the Android Studio from Eclipse just follow this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) from Google developers.

**For your problem regarding the library that does not appear on eclipse sdk folder**, try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat).

You will find them in `<sdk>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms`, if you also updated Google Repository through the SDK Manager.

The individual libraries are in `aar format`, so you'll have to extract the `jar` yourself