# Android classes.jar missing in play_services 9.2.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[a link][Missing "<sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject" folder after update to revision 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat)

Here are the steps: 
1. Rename .aar to .zip 
2. Unzip the file 
3. Create a 'libs' folder and move the classes.jar file into it 
4. Import the project into Eclipse by using New -> Project -> Android Project from Existing Source Code 
5. Go to the Project's properties and set the Build Target and 'Is Library' flag –

Question is where is the classes.jar in play services 9.2.0

Comment: Update your google repository.. check the old version like 3.0.1 & extract, Same After update you will find this in 9.2.0