# I can't find google-play-services-lib

Tags: admob, google-play-services

I followed this path -> `C:\Users\onat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services` but i can't find google-play-services-lib for my project

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find them in `<sdk>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms`, if you also updated Google Repository through the SDK Manager as stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat). The individual libraries are in `aar` format, so you'll have to extract the `jar` yourself.

You can also downgrade it back to revision 29 using the version history available on this [site](http://www.smorgasbork.com/2015/01/05/google-play-services-sdk-version-history).

Also based from this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/game-engines/djySAXCZ7HE):

> We would never recommend you to rename/edit any part of the Android
>   SDK. If you find any issues, do let us know and we would look into it.
>   As to your Mobile Ads/Unity/Android integration, I will certainly help
>   you. Please follow these steps if you are on Google Play Service
>   revision 30.0 (v 9.0) -
>
> - Make a new project and import the Mobile Ads [Unity package](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogleads%2Fgoogleads-mobile-unity%2Freleases%2Fdownload%2Fv3.0.3%2FGoogleMobileAds.unitypackage&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGO7SyCLGxb7Vs-Iz1rluDYw0oTqw).
> - Copy our [demo script](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogleads%2Fgoogleads-mobile-unity%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fsamples%2FHelloWorld%2FAssets%2FGoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.cs&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGICDRQ44qkHR4xGm1Y-yyltBSnoQ),
>     make a new empty GameObject and add the script as the component.
> - Right click on **Assets > PlayServicesResolver** folder and select **Google Play Services > Resolve Client Jars**.
> - There is a known issue with GMS revision 30 in Unity. To build for Android, you would need to select **Assets > Plugins > Android >
>     firebase-common-9.0.0.aar** file and in the Unity Inspector, deselect
>     **Android** under the **Platform for Plugins** sections.
> - Finally, edit the **Bundle Identifier** in your Player Settings and deploy your awesome project to your Android device.

The m2repository folder contains aar files used for android studio. If you look at some of the sample apps `project.properties` file you will see that the sample apps still reference the `google-play-services_lib`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer i will try

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very usefull