# how to add google play services library to nativescript

Tags: google-play-services, angular2-nativescript, google-maps-android-api-1

i am trying to add google maps api for android to a nativescript app i am working on, i am following the steps in this post [NativeScript plugin for Google Maps SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-google-sdk) , i have installed the nativescript plugin but i have having problems with the next step which is to add the google play services library to the project. i have installed google play services from android sdk manager and i am to run this command next `tns library add android "path to the GooglePlayServices SDK"` . 
example

```
tns library add android "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib"
```

but when i opened the google_play_services directory i didnt find a libproject folder.

i have searched for help and this post [Missing “/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject” folder after update to revision 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat) seems the most related . the best answer says:

> Looks like Google just broke down Google Play Services into multiple libraries. You'll find them in /extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms, if you also updated Google Repository through the SDK Manager.

The individual libraries are in aar format, so you'll have to extract the jar yourself, if that's what you're after.

Comment: See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631695/how-to-access-google-play-services-in-nativescript