# What is the dependency on google play services projects rev 32?

Tags: android, admob

In this revision google_play_services_lib is split into smaller projects and seems to be located at \extras\google\m2repository.

This answer
[Missing "<sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject" folder after update to revision 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat) ][1]

suggests to unzip and import the projects separated.

But what is the dependency on these projects? Which projects I have to import to run banners and internationals?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? What have you tried so far? Eclipse has been deprecated for over a year and a half.

Comment: Eclipse, I have projects that I'm not ready to use with Android Studio.

Comment: And still the dependency on these projects should be clear, instead its a big mystery.

Comment: There's no mystery if you're using Android Studio: it actually tells you exactly what the latest version is.

Comment: We are talking about Java projects that can be imported and build by other environments too.

Comment: And I'm not blaming myself, it was clearly a nasty trick. as was every update on this google play services.

Answer (score 1):

Per the `play-services-ads-9.4.0.pom` found in the `<sdk-dir>\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-ads\9.4.0` directory, the `play-services-ads` dependency needed for banner ads depends on to the following other libraries:

- `play-services-ads-lite`
- `play-services-clearcut`
- `play-services-gass`
- `play-services-base` (which requires `play-services-tasks`)
- `play-services-basement`

You'd need to manually package each one, including all resources. You'll also need to manually add everything in the AndroidManifest.xml in each `.aar` to your AndroidManifest.xml (these would normally be added for you by Gradle).