# Download .jar with GoogleApiClient class

Tags: android, google-api-client

This may seem a bit silly, but I cannot find where GoogleApiClient class is located. I've downloaded a few different versions of the SDK, but they all contain GooglePlayServices and they don't have the GoogleApiClient.class file.

I am not using Android Studio/Eclipse - I'm just looking for a direct download link, so I could incorporate this class into my AOSP project.

I did install Android Studio to see if I can download it through that, but the SDK it downloaded also doesn't contain GoogleApiClient.

I'm probably overseeing something very simple and I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is inside at `google-play-services.jar` archive at 
`.\com\google\android\gms\common\api\GoogleApiClient.class` path

In the file:

at `.\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\` the file `google-play-services.jar` must be existed. The file contains this class `.\com\google\android\gms\common\api\GoogleApiClient.class` . If not there is something wrong with your Android SDK.

Or better:

`.\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\4.3.23\play-services-4.3.23.aar`  > unzip it. > use class.jar <<<< this jar contains your google play class file (`GoogleApiClient.class`).

Comment: I have the google-play-services.jar, but it does not have that path - the only two folders in \common are \data and \images

Comment: Ok, I don't have that .jar file at all. My path is like this: ./sdk/extras/google/google_play_services and then only 2 folders there - docs and samples

Comment: Yes, just found http://stackoverflow.com/a/37356709/20208 (similar). Downloaded the new archive and found the class :) Thanks - it helped when I knew I was missing a folder.

Comment: Nevertheless i found the solution with SDK

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at that file too. Not sure which one is more suitable for me, as I need it for Android 4.4.2, but at least I know how to look for it now :)