# How to display Admob? It's not work why?

Tags: android, admob

I try to integrate ADMOB in my application but I do not understand why it does not work. when i try with google test ID it works but not with my ID. Here is my code:
XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3264484685894314/1550177632"
            ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

MainActivity:

```
AdView adView;


        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3264484685894314~2467851098");
        adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Est ce que mon code est bon?

The first ID of the photo I used for the MainActivity.java and the second ID for the xml layout

[The image with the IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKOyH.png)

Comment: what version of admob library are you using?  Is it through firebase?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

Comment: Im not use firebase in my application

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688617/admob-live-ads-not-appearing-in-libgdx-application-failed-to-load-ad-0/42691624#42691624)