# How to add google play services to eclipce

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, google-play, google-play-services

I used to use old version of Google Play Services in my projects. But now I keep getting warnings when I upload my apps to Google Play. These warnings says that I have to update my Google Play Services.

I have the latest version of Google Play Services in SDK manager with Rev.49

In the last versions of Google Play Services, I can find the Google Play library in the following directory:

> SDK --> /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/

But now there is no `libproject/google-play-services_lib/`. Where can I get the library?

Comment: Not sure what SDK version you have based on this list: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#revisions Eclipse is no longer the official Android IDE from Google for years. The easiest way to add Google Services is to use Android Studio and migrate to the gradle build system which is needed for multidex and other parts of the toolchain.

Comment: Soon or later you will have to move to Android Studio. Sooner you do the better. There is *almost* nobody using Eclipse for Android, therefore nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311511/8294916

Or the answer directly below it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356709/8294916

Hopefully you can migrate over to Android Studio, but if you're stuck with Eclipse because you're working on a legacy project, I feel for you! :(